# setting length right border

Tags: html, css

I would like to set the size of each of the right border of my tabs contained in my menu, or force the borders to make the entire vertical length of the menu.

Here is my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5FP8R/

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="lien_menu">
                <br>Onglet0 loooooooog</a></li>
        <li><a class="lien_menu">
                <br>Onglet1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've had plenty of time to look at the answers, please review what has been said and accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple, set the height on your

```
#menu ul
```

and

```
#menu ul li
```

to 100%. Because `#menu` has a fixed height, the `li`'s will inherit that height and stretch to fit, you may have to adjust your `#menu` height if the spacing is too large now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #menu ul li {
     display: table-cell;
     padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
     border-right: 1px solid #278fac;
     text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #278FAC;
     height: inherit;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 100px;
 }
```

The use of `display: table-cell;` works here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a height attribute to #menu ul li (like height: 60px;)

```
#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #278fac;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #278FAC;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3 feature: [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

http://jsfiddle.net/5FP8R/9/

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C20017, #C20017); 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0px solid red;
}

#menu ul {
  padding: 7px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px solid green;
  display: flex; /* this is flex-container */
  height: 70px; /* control height here */ 
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch; /* stretch items' height to container */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal align to center */
}

#menu ul li {
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #278fac;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #278FAC;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100px;
  list-style: none; /* remove list style */
}

a.lien_menu {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```